# I am trying to make my logo change when hovered in css

Tags: html, css, web

I am having difficulty trying to make the logo at the top of my web page change when I hover over it.

To be more specific, I have a logo at the top of my page, and I created another logo slightly different for when a user hovers over it.

Here is my code:

```
#top{
width:1366px;
height:100px;
background-color:#1e125b;
}

body{
    background-color:white;
    background-repeat:repeat;
    margin: 0;
}

#top:hover{
background-image: url('Logo_hover.png');
}
```

The Logo_hover multiplies itself throughout the whole div, instead of simply changing the initial image. I understand that the background-image is not what I should be using for this problem but I cannot seem to find any other solutions.

Comment: create a plunkr and share

Answer (score 1):

#top:hover{
background-image: url('Logo_hover.png');
background-repeat: none
}

Comment: I still have the same issue. What I will do now is create 2 separate divs. One for the top, and one for the logo. It might work more efficiently this way. Thanks Elijah for your help.

Answer (score 0):

have you used this.onmouseover & this.onmouseout ?

```html
<img src='your pic' onmouseover="this.src='your pic on mouse over';" onmouseout="this.src='your pic on mouse out';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.logo {
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
}

.logo:hover{
  
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image2");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#top{

        background-image: url(logo.png); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        overflow:hidden;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;


}
#top:hover{

        background-image: url(logo_hover.png);
}
```